# Get post from custom REST endpoint in Gutenberg

Tags: posts, javascript, rest-api, block-editor, endpoints

I'd like to get a post object from a custom REST endpoint within a Gutenberg block. The REST endpoint returns as part of its JSON payload an array with a "post" key which contains the contents of the `WP_Post` PHP object to return. Normally I'd get posts with `getEntityRecords` and `withSelect` in the block's JavaScript:

```
    // ...within gutenberg block...
    edit: withSelect( ( select, props ) => {
        const { attributes } = props;
        const { getEntityRecords, getPostType } = select( 'core' );

        const query = {
            post_id: 5, // this is made up!
        };

        return {
            children: getEntityRecords( 'postType', 'post', query )
        };
    } )( edit ),
```

...but this seems to only work for the standard WordPress posts REST endpoint. How can I get a post object from a custom REST endpoint within a Gutenberg block? Ideally I'd like to get a post in a form that looks identical to one retrieved using `getEntityRecords`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*(Revised answer to properly address the questions in the question..)*

### For Question 1 (JS)

> How can I get a post object from a *custom* REST endpoint within a
>   Gutenberg block?

So there's the [`apiFetch()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/packages/packages-api-fetch/) which you can use to fetch resources from the REST API.

But unlike `return { children: getEntityRecords() }`, `return { children: apiFetch() }` won't work because `apiFetch()` always returns a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) instance — `getEntityRecords()` always returns an object/array upon successful API request (and that the response is actually good).

So specifically if you want that to work with `withSelect()`, then you can add your endpoint as an entity:

1. So in PHP, you can register a custom endpoint like so:

   ```php
   register_rest_route( 'my-namespace/v1', 'posts', array( ...your args... ) )
   ```
2. And in Gutenberg, you can add it as an entity like so:

   ```js
   var dispatch = wp.data.dispatch;
   dispatch( 'core' ).addEntities( [
       {
           name: 'posts',           // route name
           kind: 'my-namespace/v1', // namespace
           baseURL: '/my-namespace/v1/posts' // API path without /wp-json
       }
   ]);
   ```

And then in your custom block:

```js
// Used with withSelect():
return {
    children: select( 'core' ).getEntityRecords( 'my-namespace/v1', 'posts' )
}
```

### For Question 2 (PHP)

> I'd like to get a post in a form that looks identical to one retrieved
>   using `getEntityRecords`.

1. You can [create your very own controller class](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/controller-classes/#controllers).
2. Or maybe extend the [`WP_REST_Posts_Controller`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/) class (which is used with the standard posts routes like [`wp/v2/posts`](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/posts/#list-posts)).
3. Or just make use of the [`prepare_item_for_response()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_posts_controller/prepare_item_for_response/) and [`prepare_response_for_collection()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_rest_controller/prepare_response_for_collection/) methods in `WP_REST_Posts_Controller`. These two methods can be used to return a list of posts.

Basic example for the third option (in actual implementation, you may want to add authorization/permissions check and/or accept custom parameters like `per_page`):

```php
class My_REST_Posts_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->namespace     = '/my-namespace/v1';
        $this->resource_name = 'posts';
    }

    public function register_routes() {
        register_rest_route( $this->namespace, '/' . $this->resource_name, array(
            array(
                'methods'  => 'GET',
                'callback' => array( $this, 'get_items' ),
            ),
        ) );
    }

    public function get_items( $request ) {
        $post_type = 'post'; // or this can be defined as a property in the class
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'post_type' => $post_type,
        ) );

        $data = array();

        if ( empty( $posts ) ) {
            return rest_ensure_response( $data );
        }

        // Here we make use of the default controller class.
        // Remember that only a single post type is supported.
        $class = new WP_REST_Posts_Controller( $post_type );

        foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
            $response = $class->prepare_item_for_response( $post, $request );
            $data[] = $class->prepare_response_for_collection( $response );
        }

        return rest_ensure_response( $data );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not actually looking for a special post type - I want to get data (which happens to be a `WP_Post`) from a custom REST endpoint. I just want the WordPress JSON library to treat what it gets from this custom REST endpoint as if it had come from `getEntityRecords`, i.e. a post object.

Comment: Does the updated answer help?

Comment: Hmm. The custom REST endpoint returns a JSON array with the `WP_Post` object. I just want to grab that in JavaScript using whatever mechanism is recommended for doing that for within a Gutenberg block. I guess it comes down to: how do I get post data from a custom REST endpoint and parse it in a way that it resembles a post retrieved using `getEntityRecord`?

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't really pay attention to the "custom REST endpoint".. but check the revised answer and hopefully that one helps. :) Let me know.

Comment: Thanks, that's it! So I guess there's no special way to treat JSON data representing a post retrieved from a custom REST endpoint. It's just an array of the post fields.

Comment: Actually, there is.. see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for updating your answer again to make it even clearer. The difference between the promise returned by `apiFetch` and `getEntityRecord` was confusing so it's good to have an explanation of the difference here. Much appreciated!